# How can I write Excel VBA code to repeat until it reaches the worksheet edge?

Tags: excel

I'd like to write some VBA that performs an action repeatedly on cells until it reaches the worksheet edge, eg column A, no matter where it started from. I've found that if I tell it to repeat more times than there are columns I get an error as the code tries to move to a column to the left of column A. How can I limit a loop to stop at column A?

For example, if I use

```
 For n = 1 To 5
'
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.merge

'
Next n
```

Then if I start this with a cell in column G selected it's OK, but if I had a cell in column F or less selected, it crashes.

Thanks!

Comment: You actually don't need a loop. Simply find the current location (column) of the cell and then construct your range and then merge it. We know that Col A is always Col 1...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I read it as merging two cells at a time, e.g., A1 and A2, B1 and B2, etc. Seems like that needs a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. Note that a key principal of VBA is that there's almost never a need to `Select` cells. (Although the macro recorder doesn't know that).

```
Sub MergeEm()
Dim n As Long
Dim cellActive As Excel.Range
Dim CellRow As Long

Set cellActive = ActiveCell
CellRow = cellActive.Row
'Stepping backwards - not necessary, but in spirit with your original code
For n = cellActive.Column To 1 Step -1
    cellActive.Parent.Cells(CellRow, n).Range("A1:A2").Merge
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great Doug, many thanks. It works fine, I'll next figure out how it works! I'm new to recent incarnations of Basic, I've a lot to learn.